# Unable to remove a Remote Event Receiver attached to a list using Remove-PnPEventReceiver .Erro "emove-PnPEventReceiver : Access denied."

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have a remote event receiver which is attached to a list. so i want to remove it, but when i try this PnP script using the Office 365 admin:-

```
Remove-PnPEventReceiver -List "Our Project"  -Identity "ProjectRER"
```

I got the following exception:-

> Remove-PnPEventReceiver : Access denied. You do not have permission to
>   perform this action or access this resource

Also i try this :-

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url *** -AppId *** -AppSecret ***>
Remove-PnPEventReceiver -Identity "ProjectRER"
```

but i got the same exception. here is the code which have attached the RER inside our provider hosted app:-

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
            if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                    {
                        //Get reference to the host web list with name Feedback
                        var documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Update System");
                        clientContext.Load(documentsList);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        string remoteUrl = "****.svc";
                                                  //Create the remote event receiver definition
                        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation newEventReceiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
                        {
                            EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated,
                            ReceiverAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                            ReceiverName = "***",
                            ReceiverClass = "***",
                            ReceiverUrl = remoteUrl,
                            SequenceNumber = 15002
                        };
                        //Add the remote event receiver to the host web list
                        documentsList.EventReceivers.Add(newEventReceiver);
                        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation newEventReceiver2 = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
                        {
                            EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdating,
                            ReceiverAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                            ReceiverName = "***2",
                            ReceiverClass = "**2",
                            ReceiverUrl = remoteUrl,
                            SequenceNumber = 15001
                        };
                        //Add the remote event receiver to the host web list
                        documentsList.EventReceivers.Add(newEventReceiver2);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi John, Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below code,

```
# replace these details (also consider using Get-Credential to enter password securely as script runs).. 
$username = "SomeUser@SomeOrg.onmicrosoft.com" 
$password = "SomePassword" 
$url = "https://SomeSite.sharepoint.com"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 

# the path here may need to change if you used e.g. C:\Lib.. 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
# note that you might need some other references (depending on what your script does) for example:
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll" 

# connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green 
} 

function deleteListItemRemoteEventReceiver([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$context, [string]$listName, [string]$receiverName)
{
    Write-Host "Attempting to delete RER with name '$receiverName' on list '$listName'"

    $list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
    $context.Load($list)
    $eventReceivers = $list.EventReceivers
    $context.Load($eventReceivers)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $specifiedEr = $null
    try
    {
        foreach ($er in $eventReceivers)
        {
            if ($er.ReceiverName -eq $receiverName)
            {
                $specifiedEr = $er
            }
        }

        if ($specifiedEr -ne $null -and !$specifiedEr.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
        {
            $specifiedEr.DeleteObject()
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "Receiver deleted successfully"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Error "Failed to find receiver with name '$receiverName'"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error "Failed to delete receiver - error:  $_"
    }
}

# now call function..
deleteListItemRemoteEventReceiver $clientContext $listName $receiverName
```

for more information, refer the below link,

https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/01/add-delete-and-list-remote-event-receivers.html

Comment: when i try running this script i got this exception `"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."`